# Set Date Created from filenames

Tags: metadata, exiftool, date

I have around 4k photos and 1k videos that have no date in metadata because I switched my phones. All of them have the dates in the filenames in the format -

```
IMG/VID-YYYYMMDD-SerialNumber
```

I don't know how to use ExifTool to accomplish this goal and little knowledge about how to use command lines to do things.

Is it possible to extract this date from the filename and set the created date as the above date in the filename? Unfortunately, renaming is not an option.

I know it's not right for me to jump in without having any prior knowledge about the subject, but these photos are hogging my gallery in a completely random pattern. I would really appreciate some help. Thank you.

Edit: I'm using Windows 10, Sorry forgot to mention...

Comment: Are you sure there isn't any metadata **in** the files?  Because changing a camera does not remove the embedded data.  I suspect that your actual problem is the file system time stamps are off.  When you right click->Properties on a file, the first things that pop up are the file system ones.  What you want to check is under the Properties->Details tab and look for "Date Taken" for photos and "Media created" for videos.  If those exists you **Do Not** want to rewrite them as you will be losing the original data.

Comment: From the command line, run this exiftool command to see all the time stamps in the file  `exiftool -G -a -s -Time:All file.jpg`  That will show you all the embedded time stamps.  The important ones would be `DateTimeOriginal` and `CreateDate`.  Also note that video time stamps are supposed to be in UTC, so they may display as being off by your time zone.